# prevent parent page refresh when submitting form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following code to POST data :

```
<form action="SaveToExcel.php" method="post" target="_blank" onsubmit='$("#datatodisplay").val( $("<div>").append( getExcel() ).html() )'>
  <input  type="image" src="../../images/floppy_disk_icon.jpg" width="16" height="16" >
  <input type="hidden" id="datatodisplay" name="datatodisplay" />       
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, the parent page is refreshed? Can I make the parent page NOT to refresh?

The SaveToExcel.php code looks like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/ms-excel");     
header("Content-Disposition: filename=export.xls");
// Fix for crappy IE bug in download.
header("Pragma: ");
header("Cache-Control: ");
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     <?=str_replace('\"','"',$_REQUEST['datatodisplay'])?>
  </body>
</html>
```

By the way, I am using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it load your form in an iframe
like this `<iframe src="yourform.html"></iframe>` and place it in your parent page now when you submit your form total page doesn't get refresh

Comment: then you use ajax form submission then page wont get refreshed

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do an ajax call while user click on submit button. You can try [jquery-ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

for extreme remove form. write separate function to call ajax while user clicks submit button. i do in this way.

Answer (score -2):

Or simply

```
return false;
```

at the end of the form submit handler.

Comment: If he wants not to refresh the parent window is by not submitting the form, isn't that right?

Comment: He wants not to refresh **after submitting the form.**